# How to use join when doing composition with Spring data JPA Specification

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, specifications

Let's say i have two static methods :

```
public static Specification<SomeEntity> isSomeValue() {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        Join<SomeEntity, JoinEntity> join = root.join("joinEntity");
        return builder.equal(join.get("someProperty"), "someValue");
    };
}
```

And

```
public static Specification<SomeEntity> isSomeOtherValue() {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        Join<SomeEntity, JoinEntity> join = root.join("joinEntity");
        return builder.equal(join.get("someOtherProperty"), "someOtherValue");
    };
}
```

I can need only one of the two or both. When i need both i would use composition and do something like

```
someEntityRepository.find(isSomeValue().and(isSomeOtherValue()));
```

My question is : Is that ok to compose specification when both methods use the same join ? Should i keep it like that or should i just do another method in order to not repeat the join ?

Of course, above are simplified fake examples. I'm trying to have a better understanding of how it works under the surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you combine these two specifications you'll end up with two joins, which is probably not what you want.
You can use `root.getJoins()` to determine if a join is already present and if so use it for the predicate and otherwise create a new join.

Comment: Yes, ending up with two joins is exactly what i want to avoid but i didn't know about root.getJoins(). I will dig into it, thank you !